# Advanced gradient

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside2

I'm trying to make simple color picker. At the beginning, it consisted of r, g, b and h, s, l sliders but later I decided to go with the more common picker, the one with a hue slider and the thing like in this image

[image]

This is my first time dealing with colors/gradients and tried to make the thing and achieve the gradient with qlineargradient and realized that's not how the gradient works. I'm not sure how to paint the gradient like in the picture programmatically. How can I paint something like it? I'm not talking about making the color picker itself but only the gradient in the image.

The following is what I've tried;

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
import pathlib
import customColorsList


class widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(widget, self).__init__()

        self.resize(300, 300)

        self.setStyleSheet("background: qlineargradient("
                           "x1:0, y1:0,"
                           "x2:1, y2:1,"
                           "stop:0 white,"
                           "stop:0.5 green,"
                           "stop:1 black);")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't achieve that using simple gradients, *but* you can use basic composition, with an horizontal QLinearGradient for the color, and a vertical for the black component.

The basic concept is like this:

```
        self.gradient = QtGui.QLinearGradient(0, 0, 1, 0)
        self.gradient.setCoordinateMode(QtGui.QGradient.ObjectBoundingMode)
        self.gradient.setColorAt(0, QtCore.Qt.white)
        self.gradient.setColorAt(0, QtCore.Qt.green)

        self.overlay = QtGui.QLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 1)
        self.overlay.setCoordinateMode(QtGui.QGradient.ObjectBoundingMode)
        self.overlay.setColorAt(0, QtCore.Qt.transparent)
        self.overlay.setColorAt(1, QtCore.Qt.black)
```

In the following example, I'm implementing a basic widget to show the color and a simple interface to change it:

[image: gradient example]

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Picker(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setMinimumSize(250, 250)

        self.gradient = QtGui.QLinearGradient(0, 0, 1, 0)
        self.gradient.setCoordinateMode(QtGui.QGradient.ObjectBoundingMode)
        self.gradient.setColorAt(0, QtCore.Qt.white)

        self.overlay = QtGui.QLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 1)
        self.overlay.setCoordinateMode(QtGui.QGradient.ObjectBoundingMode)
        self.overlay.setColorAt(0, QtCore.Qt.transparent)
        self.overlay.setColorAt(1, QtCore.Qt.black)

    def setColor(self, color):
        self.gradient.setColorAt(1, color)
        self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        qp.fillRect(self.rect(), self.gradient)
        qp.fillRect(self.rect(), self.overlay)


class Test(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.picker = Picker()
        layout.addWidget(self.picker)
        self.redSlider = QtWidgets.QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, maximum=255)
        layout.addWidget(self.redSlider)
        self.greenSlider = QtWidgets.QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, maximum=255)
        layout.addWidget(self.greenSlider)
        self.blueSlider = QtWidgets.QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, maximum=255)
        layout.addWidget(self.blueSlider)

        self.redSlider.valueChanged.connect(self.updateColor)
        self.greenSlider.valueChanged.connect(self.updateColor)
        self.blueSlider.valueChanged.connect(self.updateColor)

        self.setColor(QtGui.QColor(QtCore.Qt.green))

    def setColor(self, color):
        self.redSlider.blockSignals(True)
        self.redSlider.setValue(color.red())
        self.redSlider.blockSignals(False)

        self.greenSlider.blockSignals(True)
        self.greenSlider.setValue(color.green())
        self.greenSlider.blockSignals(False)

        self.blueSlider.blockSignals(True)
        self.blueSlider.setValue(color.blue())
        self.blueSlider.blockSignals(False)

        self.updateColor()

    def updateColor(self):
        color = QtGui.QColor(
            self.redSlider.value(), 
            self.greenSlider.value(), 
            self.blueSlider.value()
            )
        self.picker.setColor(color)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    test = Test()
    test.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```